# NMi and Jaccard measure in R

Tags: r

I am trying to find jaccard and NMI indexes from R using NMI package and cluster package of R.the thng is i am getting wrong indexes as the primary data conatins 3 clusters whereas test data has 5 clusters and 2 clusters respectively. Is there any way that NMI and jaccard indexes can be correctly calculated for data like this. following is the code which ia m presently using

```
clarax <- clara(a,3)
clV1 <- clarax$clustering
clara1 <- clara(e,5)
clV2 <- clara1$clustering 
ci <- cindex(clV1=clV1, clV2=clV2, self=FALSE, minSZ=1, method="jaccard")
ci[2:3] # Returns Jaccard index and variables used to compute it 
ci$intersects
a4<-ci$Jaccard_Index
sprintf("%.16f", a4)

clarax <- clara(a,3)
clV1 <- clarax$clustering
clara1 <- clara(f,2)
clV2 <- clara1$clustering 
ci <- cindex(clV1=clV1, clV2=clV2, self=TRUE, minSZ=1, method="jaccard")
ci[2:3] # Returns Jaccard index and variables used to compute it 
ci$intersects
a5<-ci$Jaccard_Index
sprintf("%.16f", a5)
```

and for NMI

```
b4<-NMI(groundtruth,clustering_4)
sprintf("%.16f", b4)
```

here is the link to dataset

```
http://www.mediafire.com/file/brar5msd12j552z/clustering_4.txt
http://www.mediafire.com/file/xd12xkd0h4jx6my/clustering_5.txt
http://www.mediafire.com/file/bkwat6edkcyp4wj/partitions.txt
```

the partition dataset is the primary dataset and we have to find the indexes based on these values.

Please help me out
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the problem here. NMI doesn't require the same number of clusters. Using the NMI package (as i don't find it very clear what you used in your question), it's as simple as this:

```
library(NMI)
NMI(partitions, clustering4)
```